# One to Many Relationship in QGIS with PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, one-to-many

Does anyone know of any tool that can do a One-to-Many relationship in QGIS?

I have my data in a PostGIS database.  I would like to be able to query spatial layers that are related to spatial or non spatial tables and vice versa.  I believe there was a way in ArcGIS 9.x that allowed to do something similar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a spatial table, called `location`, and another non-spatial table, `sample`. To make it spatial, a view is used called `location_sample`. The below schema is using the PostGIS 2.0 typmod syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE location(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  geom geometry(Point,4326),
  name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT location_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid),
  CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (name)
);
CREATE INDEX location_geom_idx ON location USING gist (geom);

CREATE TABLE sample(
  sid serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  location_name character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT sample_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sid),
  CONSTRAINT location_name_fkey FOREIGN KEY (location_name)
      REFERENCES location (name) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX fki_location_name_fkey ON sample USING btree (location_name);

CREATE VIEW location_sample AS
  SELECT sample.sid, location.geom, sample.location_name, sample.name
  FROM location
  LEFT JOIN sample ON sample.location_name = location.name;
```

You should be able to load up `location_sample` in QGIS or whatever GIS you are using. Assign each `sample` with a `location_name`, and it will appear at that location. If you are using QGIS 1.8, [there is an extra step to consider](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25756/1872). The "primary key" for this view is `sid` (think "sample ID").

How I've set up the [foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) between `location` and `sample` is:

- if you type a `location_name` in sample that does not exist, or is typed incorrectly (spaces, dashes, case, etc.), it will not allow you to use it (i.e., `MATCH SIMPLE`)
- if you rename a `location` (in the `name` field), then all samples connected to it will update their `location_name` fields (i.e., `ON UPDATE CASCADE`)
- if you delete a `location` row, then all samples connected to it will be deleted (i.e., `ON DELETE CASCADE`)

Read up on the foreign key constraints to get different behaviours, which might better match your situation.

You can also summarize `sample` values using aggregate functions, like `count`, `min`, `avg`, etc, and make this a similar spatial view. This makes most sense if you add numeric columns to your non-spatial table.