# Best way to join and handle multiple attributes related to the same feature

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-joins

this is not going to be a question, I'm just trying to find some advice.

Suppose I have a point shapefile (for example just two points, actually I have many more points) representing water control stations. The attribute table looks like:

```
ID    X        Y          Cl       Na
A    3480240   5887204   125.70   60.30
B    3480450   5887280   230.30   120.80
```

Now, how can I join another table that contains repeated measures of `Cl` and `Na` for each `ID`? This could be the example of the other table (measures in different years) I want to join:

```
ID    Cl       Na      Year
A    100.30   210.20   2010
A    120.40   200.30   2011
A    130.40   198.20   2012
B    101.00   199.20   2009
B    130.40   210.40   2010
B    140.60   210.00   2011
B    166.90   240.20   2012
```

I have tried both the QGIS standard join option and the mmqgis plugin (join from csv file) but the results are not as expected. 
QGIS join option adds some columns to each `ID`, but many fields have "NULL" attributes while mmqgis increased the number of rows for each `ID` and each field contains the same value (e.g. `Cl` values are always 120.20 for each year).

So I would just like to know if anybody has worked with this kind of data in order to understand the best way to handle multi-attribute field related to one single feature?

Comment: I would put the data in a postgis or spatialite database. That would give you total control of how the join in the data is done.

Comment: Something like [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26328/one-to-many-relationship-in-qgis-with-postgis].

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, so you think that it's better to use other tools and than import the table (or database) in qgis..

Comment: If you are ok with ok with some SQL, it would give you more control. There might be some tools or plugins in QGIS to do what you need. Here is another answer (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10788/how-to-join-multiple-records-to-single-feature)

Comment: Sorry matteo, I probably made wrong assumption that SQL was acceptable approach. If not, I will drop my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL approach**

Following the comment by Alexandre Neto, a combined table can be obtained using `DB Manager`:

```
SELECT ID, Na, Cl, Year_1  FROM my_table
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID, Na, Cl, null AS Year_1 FROM my_points
```

- *my_table*: table without XY
- *my_points*: XY points shapefile

(Note) I changed field "Year" of *my_table* to "Year_1" just to avoid any unforeseen troubles. "Year" could be ok.

[image]

To link the above table with the XY locations, above query is modified like:

```
SELECT combined.ID, combined.Na, combined.Cl, combined.Year_1, my_points.geometry
FROM(
    SELECT ID, Na, Cl, Year_1  FROM my_table
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ID, Na, Cl, null AS Year_1 FROM my_points
    ) AS combined
CROSS JOIN my_points
ON combined.ID = my_points.ID
```

[image]

When we use `identify features` tool at the Point A or B, it will return these records from the combined table.