# Auto column update in postgis

Tags: postgis, update

I have a fruit orchard dataset. One of the columns contain the year the orchard was planted. In  another column I would like to have the orchard age. However this pose a problem, since the age changes every year.

My question:
Is it possible to auto calculate orchard age based on the year column in postgis? If it is possible, please specify how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Make a `view` in PostgreSQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25699/how-to-make-a-spatial-view-in-postgis-and-add-it-as-a-layer-in-qgis), where the age column can be dynamically created using [some useful functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', age(now()::date, '1994-03-19'::date)) AS age;
       age
-----------------
 19 years 5 mons
(1 row)
```