# Change column order in postgis 2.0

Tags: postgis-2.0, table

Is it possible to change the column order of a table in postgresql/postgis 2.0? If so, how is it done?

Comment: What benefit would it bring to change the column order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of thing isn't directly supported with PostgreSQL. However, there are [many tips on how to alter the column positions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position).

Answer (score 9):

PostgresSQL/PostGIS is a relational database management system ( RDBMS) and the original order of the columns have no significance. If you want to change the order in which they appear, use SQL:

```
select Field2, Field3, Field1 from table;
select Field1, Field3, Field2 from table;
```

And if you want to keep this ordered result as a table in the database, use SQL Views;

```
create view "my_order" as
select Field1, Field3, Field2 from table;
```

or create new table:

```
create table "my_neworder" as
select Field2, Field3, Field1 from table;
```

And with PostGIS, use spatial views: [How to make a spatial view in PostGIS and add it as a layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25699/how-to-make-a-spatial-view-in-postgis-and-add-it-as-a-layer-in-qgis)

Comment: +1 for explaining that the order of columns (and rows) does not have any significance at all. I wish more people understood this.