# Postgresql view with Point geometry returns QGIS error “(the_geom) sql = is an invalid layer and cannot be loaded”

Tags: qgis, postgis, point

I want to create a Postgresql view using point data.  When I create the view, the geometry_columns table updates appropriately.  Attempting to load in QGIS produces the error “(the_geom) sql = is an invalid layer and cannot be loaded”.

For all of the working (polygon) views, when I load them in QGIS, I need to specify the primary key column (as documented here: [How to make a spatial view in PostGIS and add it as a layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25699/how-to-make-a-spatial-view-in-postgis-and-add-it-as-a-layer-in-qgis)).  When I try to add my point view, I am not given the option to choose the primary key.

I have tried several tables all with Point geometry and nothing is working. The tables do have the 3 constraints: enforce_dims_the_geom, enforce_geotype_the_geom, and  enforce_srid_the_geom.   I have also run st_isvalidreason (the_geom) and the geometry is valid.  How do I get a view with point data to show the selection for a primary key in QGIS?

We are running PostGIS 1.4 and I am using QGIS 1.8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a spatial view in PostGIS and add it as a layer in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25699/how-to-make-a-spatial-view-in-postgis-and-add-it-as-a-layer-in-qgis)

Answer (score 3):

Once you connect to the PostGIS db and a window appears with the list of available tables, if you scroll over to the right, there should be a column "Primary Key". For tables where QGIS doesn't recognize the PK, there should be a drop down so you can choose which column is the PK. If you have a column in the database table called "gid" which is a PK, then this should work without any need to manually choose the column.