# Error on QGIS with PostgreSQL views?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a PostGIS database with various tables and views. With pgAdmin I can make requests on the tables, on the views, all is working.
I add tables in QGIS 2.8, it's working, I can read, write, modify the data.
I can add views in QGIS, for all of them except two, it works.
For two views, a QGIS error window says the layer "is an invalid layer and cannot be loaded".

But I have tested on pgAdmin, the views are good and quick the load data.

So I modify the views with :

`ADD OR REPLACE VIEW x AS (/*SQL code*/ LIMIT 10);`

And now I can add the views in qGIS, and it works.

I modify the views to remove the `LIMIT 10`. And in qGIS I can see the views and ask informations about entities, all is good.

But if I save the QQIS project, on restart the layer fails to load.

I think the problem is in QGIS. But how can I know the way QGIS checks all the shapes.

Comment: Have you checked http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25699/how-to-make-a-spatial-view-in-postgis-and-add-it-as-a-layer-in-qgis, especially the part about unique integer id column? Try QGIS 2.10 which should not require this unique integer id.

Comment: Can you please post the actual SQL in the CREATE VIEW statement?

Comment: Are you sure your query returns only one type of geometries?