# Getting only one feature from MySQL

Tags: qgis, mysql

I would like to get only one feature from a MySQL database.

I use the Add Vector Layer functionality in QGIS to get the features (polygons) from the MySQL database. They are all displaying fine, but my problem is that I would like to get only one feature/polygon from the database, filtering by a MySQL query by example (it would be perfect).

Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) executable, which supports MySQL (if you're using PostgreSQL, see `pgsql2shp` and `shp2pgsql`). I'm using it like this and it works fine.

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -where "YOUR SQL CONDITION" -f "ESRI Shapefile" SHPCREATED.shp MYSQL:vine,host=localhost,user=root YOURTABLE
```

If you're under Mac OS X, the executable has been installed in `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.9/Programs/`

I was looking for a solution which was possible in command-line, because I'm working on a website and I would like to do these tasks automatically. Therefore, this is perfect for me.

Answer (score 3):

When you connect to your database and after you selected the table your wish to view, there is a button which says **"Build Query"**. And then you tell qgis which features you want to fetch.

[image: connect-window]
[image: query-window]

If for some reason you cannot access the build-in query builder you can create a [View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29).

Go in the database and enter,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myView AS SELECT * FROM <SPATIAL_TABLE> where <constraints>;
```

And then point QGIS at the created view. Also check [How to create a table from existing tables (applying new schemas) in postgis DB?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25591) for more details.